# Should we synonymize/merge [asp.net-web-api2] with [asp.net-web-api]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

It seems to me like the [asp.net-web-api2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api2) tag should be synonymized or merged with [asp.net-web-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api) since it is a one-for-one replacement of the package (Microsoft released version 2 of the package back in 2014). For example, in NuGet, there is only Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi (and you can choose various versions). The two are fully compatible to my knowledge, with the newer versions just adding a few features & bug fixes. There are, in fact, about a dozen different incremental versions of the NuGet package... but they're all just minor bugfixes.

As you can see, there's no option in Visual Studio (2019 pictured below) for which version when creating a project that utilizes it... just a yes/no checkbox:

[image]

*Note: the* [asp.net-core-webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-webapi) *tag is something wholly different, and not part of this question.*